# Writing CipherInputStream to a text file

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt an encrypted data which is stored in a text file. I use the same key and IV to encrypt and decrypt, and transfer it via configuration file.

When I print CipherInputStream to the console I do get some content, but when I try to write it to a text file I don't get any content in it.

This is the piece of code refferes to my problem:

```
File encryptedData = new File("C:\\Users\\Victoria\\Desktop\\encryptedData.txt");
File decryptedData = new File("C:\\Users\\Victoria\\Desktop\\decryptedData.txt");
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(encryptedData);
byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) decryptedData.length()];
inputStream.read(inputBytes);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, newkey, newiv, SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"));
CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher);
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(decryptedData);
System.out.println("cipherInputStream: " + cipherInputStream);  

// Writing the decrypted content to an output file
byte[] buff = new byte[1024 * 10];
int length;
while ((length = cipherInputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
    outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
}
bufin.close();
outputStream.close();
cipherInputStream.close();
```

Any solutions?
Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to put the runtime into the title, it's already in the tags.

Answer (score 2):

> Encrypted data which is stored in a text file

This is already a contradiction in terms. Encrypted data is binary, not text, and should not be stored in files with the `.txt` extension.

```
byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) decryptedData.length()];
```

This line of code is meaningless. You don't yet know how long the decrypted data will be. The decrypted file may not even exist, in which case this will produce a zero length array; or it may be different from what is about to be produced, in which case it is the wrong length.

```
inputStream.read(inputBytes);
```

Remove this line and the one before it.

1. It reads into an array which is at best sized to the size of the decrypted data, which is the wrong size for encrypted data, and at worst is just the wrong size, or even zero length, as shown above.
2. It reads the input probably until that wrongly sized buffer is full, and you then (a) completely ignore the data read and (b) attempt to read the same stream further, which will fail in the decryption loop, or at best produce incorrect output, as you may not be decrypting all the data.

> When I print CipherInputStream to the console I do get some content

No you don't. You get a piece of data of the general form `CipherInputStream@0011223344`, which is just the result of calling `CipherInputStream.toString()`, which does *not* contain any 'content'.

Comment: First of all, thank you! I'm new to encryption and to Java in general, and I'll fix my code as you suggest